# ADF: Table contains comma and I want to output using delimiter text

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need some help with using delimited text as a sink. I have a SQL table and one of the columns contains a comma. However, I want to export the data as a delimited text file using comma as column delimiter.

In my source I am using an inline linked service to my database. Then in my source options I have added my select query statement to select the required data.

I do not want any of the data to have double quotes or any other characters. I can't seem to find a way around this problem. Can anyone help?

Database table example:

Name Age Address
Tom  10  100 London Road, London UK

Expected delimited file:
Tom,10,100 London Road, London UK

Current output:
Tom,10,100 London Road~,London UK

[image]

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve your expected output using DataFlow activity.

**Step1:** Select DataFlow activity

[image]

**Step2:**
Below is Source SQL Table

[image]

Add SQL as Source.

[image]

**Step3:** Use Select activity for mapping.

[image]

**Step4:** Use Sink as CSV file.

[image]

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

---

**Edit** - My Sink Configuration

[image]

Comment: did you have the same settings for the dataset as me? I am still not getting this output

Comment: @user406480 Added Sink Configuration, Please check Updated answer.